# Why are the numbers not written down in Ki Sisa?

Tags: bo, pinchas, parashat-ki-tisa, parshat-nasso, bamidbar-parsha

According to the very first Rashi in Seder Bamidbar:

> מתוך חיבתן לפניו מונה אותם כל שעה כשיצאו ממצרים מנאן וכשנפלו בעגל מנאן לידע מנין הנותרים כשבא להשרות שכינתו עליהן מנאן. באחד בניסן הוקם המשכן ובאחד באייר מנאם:

the Bnei Yisrael were counted three times by this point: when they left Mitzraim (Shemos 12:37), when they fell by the Eigel (30:11-16, I assume; Rashi to 31:18 says that the Eigel took place long before those pesukim even though it’s written after), and when the Shechinah came to rest on them (Bamidbar 1:1-4:49).

They are subsequently counted a fourth time, after the plague (26:1-65).

Three of these are different than the fourth, though. The one after the Eigel merely discusses how to count, but doesn’t actually detail how many people were counted. All the others give at least a sum total, while this one gives no total at all. Why is this the case?